# Receiving Null in ajax to Controller post request in codeginitor

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

i want to send data from ajax function to controller in codeignitor but i m getting Null

```
 $.ajax({
        url:'shop/compare/getProductMeta',
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "json",
        data: {"proId": proID},
        success:function(data)
        {   
            for (i =0; i< data.length;  i++) {
                alert(data[i]);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert('here 1');
         }

    });
```

in codeignitor controller i m reciving data as

```
public function compare($param1)
{
    if($param1=='getProduct')
    {
        $result=$this->metaCRUD->getAllProducts();
        echo json_encode($result);
    }elseif ($param1=='getItem') {
        $result=$this->siteCRUD->getAlItems();
        echo json_encode($result);

    }elseif($param1=='getProductMeta')
    {
        $pid=$this->input->post("proId");
        echo ('value'.$pid);
        $result=$this->siteCRUD->getProductMeta($pid);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }

}
```

i m getting NULL here

Comment: have you tried $_POST['proId'] in the place of $pid=$this->input->post("proId") just try that to verify if you have value in POST or not.

Comment: `<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: proId</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/shop.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 79</p>


 <p>Backtrace:</p>`

Comment: here hi what i got when i did this

Comment: check the answer and try that change.

Comment: you might want to look into this: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace code with this one

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'shop/compare/getProductMeta',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {"proId": proID},
   error: function() {
      alert('Something is wrong');
   },
   success: function(data) {
        for (i =0; i< data.length;  i++) {
            alert(data[i]);
        }  
   }
});
```

if you have still issue just try to print `$_POST` to see what type of data you are getting.

Comment: Still same Problem

Comment: wheni debug netwok  i get proId=1 but not getting in post

Comment: try to print "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); at the place of echo ('value'.$pid);

Comment: Array
(
    [proId] => 1
)

Comment: that means you are getting data now just print it $_POST["proId"]; and it should work.

Comment: @AlyHunzik at least mark the answer correct :) when someone helps.

Comment: i clickedpn up arrow on your answer i dont know know why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

`data: {proId: proID}` .. without quotes and make sure the value is correct not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

remove `contentType: "json"` or just like the answer of @ashfaq-ahmed